# Bitcoin network information pubkeyhash privatekey

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcore, blockexplorer

I am trying to set up a https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore Insight node but for a forked coin of Bitcoin. To complete the task I need to modify the following information but with the forks version.

```
addNetwork({
  name: 'livenet',
  alias: 'mainnet',
  pubkeyhash: 0x00,
  privatekey: 0x80,
  scripthash: 0x05,
  xpubkey: 0x0488b21e,
  xprivkey: 0x0488ade4,
  networkMagic: 0xf9beb4d9,
  port: 8333,
  dnsSeeds: [
    'seed.bitcoin.sipa.be',
    'dnsseed.bluematt.me',
    'dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org',
    'seed.bitcoinstats.com',
    'seed.bitnodes.io',
    'bitseed.xf2.org'
```

Other than the seeds and port I have no idea how to find the other information with the Bitcoin client/source code. How is these values determined and how can I produce them?

Comment: I have the same question on another fork, apparently the guy that know how to do this is a ghost.